# Apply Plyfit Function to find the slope for each dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I am trying to apply the following function to calculate the slope and intercept for each dataframe column:

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
def fit_line(x, y):
     """Return slope, intercept of best fit line."""
     # Remove entries where either x or y is NaN.
     clean_data = pd.concat([x, y], 1).dropna(0) # row-wise
     (_, x), (_, y) = clean_data.iteritems()
     slope, intercept, r, p, stderr = linregress(x, y)
     return slope, intercept
```

I create a new dataframe with two columns, however, I don't really know how to pass the first columns as (x) and other columns as y?

```
df['m'], df['b']  = df_freq.apply(fit_line(x?, y?), axis=1)
```

here are the columns for the dataframe all data are floats.

Index(['Time', '5', '10', '15', '20', '25', '30', '35', '40', '45', '50', '55',
       '60', '65', '70', '75', '80', '85', '90', '95', '100', '105', '110',
       '115', '120', '125', '130', '135', '140', '145', '150', '155', '160',
       '165', '170', '175', '180', '185', '190', '195', '200', '205', '210',
       '215', '220', '225', '230', '235', '240', '245'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: I think you added only the index, which is, by the way are not floats but objects since the first value is 'Time'. Does your df contain columns with y-values?

Comment: the column 'Time' is x all other  '5', '10', '15', '20' ....  '240', '245' should be send to fit_line() as y by one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited: Sorry i missread your question.

Edited 2: Taken into account that append is not inplace by default

I think it will be the easiest to use a for loop for want you want to achieve. Assuming you have different columns with y-values and the index as x-values:

```
df_fit_parameter = pd.DataFrame()
for column in df_freq.columns:
  df_lin_fit = df_freq[column].dropna()
  slope, intercept, r, p, stderr = linregress(df_lin_fit.index, df_lin_fit)
  df_fit_parameter = df_fit_parameter.append(pd.DataFrame({'m':slope,'b':intercept}, index=[column]))
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, however, I got the following error!

"fit_line() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'", 'occurred at index 0'

Comment: Could you post a few lines of your df_freq dataframe?

Comment: I tried the code snippet that you posted, but I can't figure why df_fit_parameter does not have data even though linregress return the regression values?!

Comment: Sorry was my bad, i didn't take into account that pandas append is not acting inplace (which means that the df calling append is not changed itself) by default. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks, it is perfect :)